# boundary defining functions

Tags: differential-geometry, physics

Suppose that $M$ is the interior of a compact manifold with boundary $\partial M$. I'm often faced with so called boundary defining functions - or just 'defining functions'. That are by definition  functions $f \in C^{\infty}(\overline{M})$ with the following properties:

(i) $f(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in M$

(ii)$f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x \in \partial M$

(iii) $df \neq 0 \ on \  \partial M$

I need to know what the third property does exactly mean. Often it also is just referred as "has no zeroes on the boundary", "... has a non-vanishing differential there" or "has a non-degenerate differential there".

For me, the differential of a map $f: M \rightarrow N$ at a point p is a linear map 
$df_p : T_pM \rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$.

Does property (iii) mean:
For $v \in T_pM$ with $df_p(v)=0 \Rightarrow v = 0$ (That would be the interpreation: For every point on the boundary, the differential has no other zero than the zero vector.)

Or does it mean: The differential at the point p isn't the zero map, in other words: For every point p on the boundary $\exists v \in T_pM$ with $df_p(v) \neq 0$

Thank you for your help!

Robin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third property $df\ne 0$ means that the differential is not the zero map $T_pM\to T_{f(p)}M$ (i.e. does not map *every* tangent vector of $T_pM$ to $0\in T_{f(p)}M$). Since the defining function $f(\cdot)$ vanishes identically on the boundary as property (ii) entails, then that means $df$ acting on any vector tangent to $\partial M$ will vanish (because the directional rate of change of $f$ is just plain zero), so your first interpretation is most certainly false and impossible.

Answer (score 7):

Since $f:\bar{M} \to\mathbb{R}$, and the target space $\mathbb{R}$ is one-dimensional, the statement $df\neq 0$ is equivalent to saying that $df$, as a map between smooth manifolds (with boundary), is surjective. So the conditions imply that 0 is a regular value of $f$ and all that entails (in particular $\partial M$ is a submanifold).

Perhaps it is clearer to give an example of what may go wrong when $df$ is not required to be everywhere non-zero along $\partial M$. Consider $M$ to be the two dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\{y^3 > x^2\}$. The boundary set is given by $\{ y^3 = x^2\}$. We can putatively consider $f(x,y) = y^3 - x^2$ as a candidate for a defining function: it is positive in the interior of $M$, and it vanishes on the boundary. But you note that

$$ df = 3y dy - 2x dx $$

vanishes at the origin. And precisely at the origin you see that there is a problem: the one dimensional boundary has a cusp point there, and $\partial M$ is **not** a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Since I only can accept one answer I'd like to underline that both answers were very helpful to me.